# What is this triangular part of a sidebar menu called?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

[image: See attachment]

I've circled it in red. What is the design name of this element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people call it an arrow or a caret that enables a slide-out of content or a popup can display some sort of information.  In this particular instance it would appear it is for the navigation.  Since you tagged this with CSS I included an example of how to create it:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #b34ae5;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(179, 74, 229, 0);
    border-left-color: #b34ae5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Caret question in regards to Boorstrap that might help you: "[How is the caret on Twitter Bootstrap constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404923/how-is-the-caret-on-twitter-bootstrap-constructed)"

Comment: If you have a gradient (like it seems to have in the picture), you'll have to use an actual element that's rotated and moved around a bit, SVG, or `clip-path`